# Реализация обычной тассировки

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста,укажите на ошибки при реализации тассировки. Не могу понять принцип работы `#ifdef` , `#else` и `#define`.

Реализую класс `Trace.h` с шаблонным методом для записи. В нем же реализую мои макросы. Подскажите пожалуйста , на том ли я пути стою?
Файл `TRACE.txt` лежит там же что и исполнимый файл.

Итог: ничего не записывает в файл.

Думаю, что ошибка в определении макросов.

Код:

(Trace.h)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 

class Trace
{
public:

    Trace()
    {
        std::ofstream TraceFileWrite("TRACE.txt");
    }

    template <class T>
    void writingData(T object)
    {
          TraceFileWrite << T;
    }
    ~Trace()
    {
    //  TraceFileWrite.close();
    }
};

#ifdef Enabled_Trace 
#define Enabled_Trace(object) writingData(object)
#else 
#define Enabled_Trace(object)
#endif
```

(Source.cpp)

```
#include "Trace.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int a=7;
    double b=93.09432;
    std::string str("Hello");

    Enabled_Trace(a)
    Enabled_Trace(b)
    Enabled_Trace(str)

    std::cout<<"Hello Trace!"<<std::endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Выглядит так, как будто вы в стеке конструктора создаете экземпляр `TraceFileWrite` класса `std::ofstream`, который уничтожается при выходе из конструктора.

Comment: @AlexanderZonov так думаю происходит, как вы сказали.  Тогда лучше создать объект в приватном доступе и работать дальше с ним в конструкторе. А можете подсказать правильна реализация макросов , я, честно говоря , не уверен в её правильности?

Comment: "Итог: ничего не записывает в файл." Вы что-то выдумываете. То, что вы тут привели, не компилируемо в принципе. Поэтому итог пока только один - код не компилируется.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я думаю, вы хотели сделать нечто вроде этого:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>


#define Enable_Trace

#if defined(Enable_Trace)

class Trace
{
public:

    static Trace& tracer()
    {
        static Trace t;
        return t;
    }

    template <class T>
    void writingData(const T& object)
    {
          TraceFileWrite << object;
    }
private:
    Trace()
    {
        TraceFileWrite.open("TRACE.txt");
        // Проверки, что открыт
    }

    ~Trace()
    {
        TraceFileWrite.close();
    }
    std::ofstream TraceFileWrite;
};

#define  doTrace(x) { Trace::tracer().writingData(#x" = "); \
    Trace::tracer().writingData((x)); \
    Trace::tracer().writingData("\n"); }

#else
#define doTrace(x)
#endif



int main()
{
    int a=7;
    double b=93.09432;
    std::string str("Hello");

    doTrace(a);
    doTrace(b);
    doTrace(str);

    std::cout<<"Hello Trace!"<<std::endl;
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

Надеюсь, вы разберетесь, как и что тут работает, и по файлам разнесете. Вкратце - если `Enable_Trace` определен - есть класс `Trace` и определен макрос для его использования. Класс - синглтон (файл трассировки единственный).

Добавлю только, что я бы, пожалуй, не затирал файл трассировки, а делал его дописываемым.

Comment: Да, это то, что я хотел. Спасибо, вы очень помогли! Мне все понятно, кроме статического метода `static Trace& tracer()`для чего он служит?

Comment: Можно было обойтись без него?Как я знаю,что static функция нужна ,когда такой метод относиться к  классу в целом, а не к кому-то отдельному объекту.

Comment: Поищите, что такое "шаблон проектирования Singleton". Смысл - что объект класса трассировки у вас должен быть один и только один, иначе вы начнете сами себе портить файл трассировки. Можно было бы эту функцию сделать свободной, не принадлежащей классу - но так мы четко даем понять, что она намертво связана с этим классом. Мне кажется, что так удобнее...

Comment: спасибо ещё раз , все понятно , буду разбирать тонкости!